# changes in directive scope variables don't update the parent scope variables. Angular Js 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

This is my controller

```
 function commentController($stateParams, commentFactory, $rootScope){
  const ctrl = this;
  ctrl.comment = {};
  ctrl.decision = {};
  ctrl.$onInit = function(){
    ctrl.decision.replyVisible = false;
  }

export {commentController}
```

This is my component

```
import {commentController} from './comment.controller'

export const commentComponent = 'commentComponent'
export const commentComponentOptions = {
  bindings: {
    post: '<'
  },
  templateUrl: 'blog/src/app/components/post/comment/comment.html',
  controller: ['$stateParams', 'commentFactory', '$rootScope', commentController],
  controllerAs: 'cm'
}
```

This is my directive

```
 function showReply(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      collapsed: '<'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', ()=>{
        console.log(`Trying to hide ${scope.collapsed}`);
        scope.collapsed = true
        console.log(`Trying to hide ${scope.collapsed}`);
      })
    }
  }
}

function hideReply(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      collapsed: '<'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', ()=>{
        scope.collapsed = false;
        console.log(`Trying to hide scope.replyVisible is ${scope.collapsed}`);
      })
    }
  }
}

export {showReply, hideReply}
```

This is my html

```
 <div class="comment_wrapper">
  <div class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in cm.post.comments">
    <h3>{{comment.author.name}}</h3>
    <a href="" ng-hre="mailto:{{comment.author.email}}"></a>
    <p ng-bind-html="comment.comment"></p>
    <button show-reply collapsed="cm.decision.replyVisible">Reply</button>
    <div class="reply_wrapper" ng-show="cm.decision.replyVisible">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="cm.comment.author.name">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" ng-model="cm.comment.author.email">
      <label for="comment">Comment</label>
      <textarea name="" id="comment" cols="10" rows="5" ng-model="cm.comment.comment"></textarea>
      <button ng-click="cm.reply(comment._id)">Submit</button> <button hide-reply collapsed="cm.decision.replyVisible">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my module

```
import angular from 'angular'
import {showReply, hideReply} from './comment.directive'
import {commentFactory, commentFactoryFunc} from './comment.factory'
import {commentComponent, commentComponentOptions} from './comment.component'

export const comment = angular.module('comment', [uiRouter])
.factory(commentFactory, ['$http', commentFactoryFunc])
.component(commentComponent, commentComponentOptions)
.directive('showReply', showReply)
.directive('hideReply', hideReply)
.name
```

Here's what I am trying to do, in my html, I want to show the reply form when someone clicks on the reply button. And since there are multiple comments for with each having a reply form, I can't use the regular `ng-click`.

The changes made to the `scope.collapsed` don't get reflected on `cm.decision.replyVisible`

How do I make this work? I have always been confused about accessing parent controller variables from a directive.

Comment: Probably because you use one-way binding `post: '<'` try to `post: '='`

Comment: It's not about `post` I am trying to hide the reply form. and also, I am trying to avoid two-way data binding as it is mentioned by so many people with the introduction of Angular 1.5

Comment: Yes, sorry, its about `collapsed: '='`, If you want to change something in parent from child, you need to use two-way binding.

Comment: But I have a reply form for each comment. If I bind `collapsed` via two-way data binding, then it will reflect the changes on other reply forms too.

Comment: Yes, you need to hold state `collapsed` in  `comment.decision.replyVisible` instead of `cm`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. What is `comment` in here? I mean it would be just another object, so how would it be different from `cm`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143077/discussion-between-leguest-and-ayush-bahuguna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `comment.decision.replyVisible` instead of `cm.decision.replyVisible`

HTML

```
 <div class="comment_wrapper">
  <div class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in cm.post.comments">
    <h3>{{comment.author.name}}</h3>
    <a href="" ng-hre="mailto:{{comment.author.email}}"></a>
    <p ng-bind-html="comment.comment"></p>
   <button show-reply 
     collapsed="comment.decision.replyVisible">Reply</button>
   <div class="reply_wrapper" ng-show="comment.decision.replyVisible">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="cm.comment.author.name">
     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" id="email" ng-model="cm.comment.author.email">
     <label for="comment">Comment</label>
     <textarea name="" id="comment" cols="10" rows="5" ng-model="cm.comment.comment"></textarea>
     <button ng-click="cm.reply(comment._id)">Submit</button> <button hide-reply collapsed="cm.decision.replyVisible">Cancel</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey this didn't work. To be honest, I don't want to make the reply forms dependent on ng-repeat element because the data is coming from backend. I even tried two way data binding on `collapsed` variable. That didn't work, then I coupled it with `scope.$apply` but that reflected change on every reply form

Comment: Hey, so I finally went ahead with your solution. Although, the fact that I had to iterate over the comments array in my post object that i receive from the server, and create a new property `replyVisible` and set it to `false`, doesn't make me feel good. But thanks for your help. i'll kep this solution, till the I can find a better one.